# ¿Qué nombre recibe este sonido (o la acción de producirlo)?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

¿Cómo se llama (si es que tiene un nombre) el sonido, grito o aullido de guerra que vemos en las películas que los indios nativos americanos hacen cuando van a entrar en combate (o están muy enojados o excitados)?

Es como una especie de aullido, pero se colocan la palma de la mano enfrente de la boca de manera intermitente y muy rápida.

No sé describirlo mejor. Quizá por eso no estoy teniendo mucho éxito con mis resultados de búsqueda por Internet. Alguien sabe si ese sonido (o la acción de producir ese sonido) tiene un nombre especifico?

**Nota**: los indios hacen muchos otros sonidos con las manos y la boca, como imitar sonidos de animales para mandarse señales, pero mi pregunta es específicamente por el nombre del "aullido de guerra".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Francamente no creo que exista una palabra para decir eso. Pero te puedo dar alguna sugerencia, aunque probablemente ya pensaste en algo como esto.

Primero que nada, el grito original de los indígenas norteamericanos se hacía con la garganta. Era admirable porque sonaba fuerte e intimidante a pesar de su tremenda dificultad. Los golpecitos con la mano en la boca son solo un recurso del "hombre blanco" para imitar el sonido (que los directores de películas de vaqueros se compraron).

La palabra propia para un grito de guerra es **alarido**. No existe un verbo afín: la palabra *alardear* evolucionó hacia otro lado y no está clara su relación etimológica. Pero se puede decir **dar alaridos** o **ulular**.

El verbo **ulular** es de origen latino y significa según la RAE "dar gritos o alaridos". Los búhos ululan. Puedes escuchar en [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezaBqCf0hv0) algunos gritos de búhos con reminicencias al *indian yelling* (si se me permite hacer la analogía, aunque en realidad es bastante subjetivo). También se dice que el viento ulula.

La interjección española **olé**, un auténtico grito de guerra, probablemente deriva de **ulular**.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que, siguiendo tu nota, no respondí la pregunta.

Comment: Es una buena respuesta. Me parece interesante y relevante. Es posible que, pese a todo, ese sonido o esa acción no tenga un nombre específico. +1 de momento (voy a dejar pasar más tiempo a ver qué aportan otros usuarios y luego aceptaré una respuesta). Quizá alguien aficionado a novelas de vaqueros (o similar material escrito) puede aportar algún otro dato interesante.

Comment: Me permito comentar aquí en vez de dar una nueva respuesta, porque esta me parece buena. No conozco una mejor descripción, aunque sí he encontrado una curiosidad: [chivateo](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/diccionario/es-en/chivateo.php). En todo caso podría decir que se ha usado mucho la onomatopeya del grito al que se refiera cada uno, como Hoka-hey o Hiahou (indios Sioux), Guazábara (indios Taínos)...

Comment: Me parece que no existe una palabra para describirlo en español. Lo que sí se usa es "grito de guerra", que creo que es lo que buscas

Answer (score 6):

El término más preciso para los gritos de guerra de los  indígenas norteamericanos a los que te refieres / acción de producirlos sería en todo caso: **"japapeo" / "japapear"**. Enlazo algunos ejemplos de su uso:

*[...] cuya imagen fantasmagórica aún resonaba con sus **japapeos**(grito de guerra india) en el imaginario criollo/mestizo [...]*

http://www.rebelion.org/hemeroteca/cultura/mamani250802.htm

*[...] los devotos se visten de cuñas, chiriguanos, matacos y negras sanqueras, los cuales recorren las calles del pueblo causando ruido con sus **“japapeos”** o gritos de guerra. [...]*

https://periodicolaregion.wordpress.com/category/cultura/page/8/

*[...] La gritería y el atronante **japapeo** languidecían; la derrota no debía tardar en pronunciarse.  [...]*

http://archive.org/stream/detarijaalaasun00quijgoog/detarijaalaasun00quijgoog_djvu.txt

Answer (score -1):

Estoy de acuerdo con todo lo anterior, pero se llaman ulular y también se les conoce como japapaeo.

Ahora en la cultura egipcia estos gritos eran usados por las mujeres para despedir a sus hijos o esposo cuando se iban a la guerra o para expresar el dolor en un velorio, también cuando la gente se casaba en muestra de alegría.

El grito se llama en la cultura árabe Zaghareet que se pronuncia "zagarit" y en internet hay tutoriales que explican cómo hacer ese grito, y que en egipto la técnica sonora lo hacían repitiendo la frase "ra" por el dios del sol. Si usas esa misma técnica pero con otras vocales o consonantes podrás reproducir seguramente el grito indígena americano, por que la técnica es muy similar.

Comment: Tanto ulular como japapaeo ya habian sido incluidos en respuestas anteriores.